# Using Transactions in Sails.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, sails.js

Using Sails.js, There is no support for using database transactions. Even workarounds using .query method forces you to write actual sql syntax, to handle connection pooling which node.js use for parallel queries.

The only solution I could found is this library

[sails-mysql-transactions](https://github.com/postmanlabs/sails-mysql-transactions)

Does it support connection pooling?

Comment: yes, sails-mysql-transactions supports connection pooling.